# Is it possible to add on characters to a file name?

Tags: php, lightbox

I was just wondering if it is possible to add on characters to a file name when calling it from a database using PHP.

For example, i have the following code to pull out an image in PHP, i want it so that when the user clicks on the image it will display the image in a bigger size.

```
<a href='.$file_name.' rel="lightbox[images]" title="'.$year.' - '.$description.'">
            <img src='.$file_name.' />
</a>
```

I have all the images in a larger size with the same file name except they have _lg at the end.

I have tried many solutions using the actual lightbox code i am using but i cant get any to work so i thought this may work instead.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the file names that are returned versus the ones you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this by changing my code to this:

```
<a href='.$file_name.'_lg.jpg'.' rel="lightbox[images]" title="'.$year.' - '.$description.'">
            <img src='.$file_name.'.jpg />
```

But first i had to change the image path in the database, i had to delete the .jpg at the end and manually add it using $filename.'.jpg

Comment: Though if you do it like this you're assuming all the images are always jpg. What if you also have PNG or GIF or other kind of images?

Comment: This is a short term solution, I do have another problem with this too, if a user uploads an image to the gallery, it cannot be viewed larger.  Is there a way to just make the images larger in lightbox? @Harprog

Comment: I don't get what you mean by the other problem. Please try to explain in more detail.

Comment: If a user clicks on the image, it shows the pop up window(lightbox).  I want it to be a bigger size, preferably without having to call the _lg images. @Haprog

Comment: You would have to check the documentation of the lightbox library you're using. You probably need some changes to your JavaScript and/or CSS, but what you describe should be possible, although you need to use large enough images originally or you will get bad image quality as the browser is used for scaling up a lower resolution image.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change how the data is stored in your database.

```
function get_larger($file_name)
{
    return pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '_lg.' . pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
}
```

Then you just need to call the `get_larger` function in the `href` value:

```
<a href='.get_larger($file_name).' rel="lightbox[images]" title="'.$year.' - '.$description.'">
            <img src='.$file_name.' />
</a>
```

This would allow users to upload more extensions than just ".jpg" one.

Answer (score 0):

Append *_lg* to your filename..

```
 $file = explode(".", $file_name);

 <a href="'.$file[0].'_lg'.$file[1].'" rel="lightbox[images]" title="'.$year.' - '.$description.'">
        <img src='.$file_name.' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link href should probably link to the larger version. Something like:

```
echo '<a href="'.$file_name_large.'" rel="lightbox[images]" title="'.$year.' - '.$description.'">
    <img src="'.$file_name.'" />
</a>';
```

But you would need to get or construct the right file name for the larger image somehow. You could also store the filename of the larger version in the DB and just use that, or if the file names are like "image1.jpg" and "image1_lg.jpg" and you only store the smaller size image name in DB you need to use some string processing functions to construct one filename from the other.

Basically you would need to split the string by the last dot in the filename (assuming the filenames contain some usual file extension) and add the "_lg" string just before the last dot to get the other filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this while looping.

```
<?php

$file_name = "some.image.01.jpg";
$large_file_name = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "_lg." . pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
?>

<a href='.$large_file_name.' rel="lightbox[images]" title="'.$year.' - '.$description.'">
            <img src='.$file_name.' />
</a>
```

Comment: Your code assumes the filename only has one dot in it. It does not handle filenames with multiple dots as intended.

Comment: What about if `$file_name` contains more than one dot ?

Comment: I have updated it to make it work with file names consisting more than 1 dot.